# How can one remove all characters including and after a certain character in a pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df as seen below. How can I remove all of the characters in the Player column including and after the '/', just leaving the players name?

I have

```
  Player                PPG
Kobe Bryant/kb24       27.6
LeBron James/LJ23      24.5
DeMar DeRozan/DD10     20.1
```

I would like:

```
  Player                PPG
Kobe Bryant            27.6
LeBron James           24.5
DeMar DeRozan          20.1
```

Comment: `df['Player'].str.split('/').str[0]`

Comment: Or `df['Player'].str.replace('/.*', '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df['Player'] = df['Player'].str.split('/').str[0]
```